# SQL Tuning (Optimization) For Statement Using Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I have a SQL Statement that is running really slow, and I was wondering if there is a better way to write it.  Maybe using WHERE EXISTS instead of DISTINCT?  I am unsure.  Thank you.

```
SELECT distinct
b.ClientID,
b.FillDate as 'Fill_Date', 
b.MEDNbr as 'MED'
FROM
  [MedDB].[dbo].[Claim] b
  LEFT JOIN [MedDB].[dbo].[Store] c
  on b.StoreID = c.StoreID
  LEFT JOIN [MedDB].[dbo].[StoreGroup] d
  on c.StoreGroupID = d.StoreGroupID 
  left join [MedDB].dbo.[carrier] e
  on b.carrierId = e.carrierId
  left outer join [MedDB].dbo.[CarrierGroupCarrier] f
  on b.carrierID = f.carrierId
  left join [MedDB].dbo.[CarrierGroup] g
  on f.CarrierGroupId = g.CarrierGroupId

  WHERE
  b.MEDNbr = 1
  and b.CloseDate is NULL 
  and b. OpenClaimAmt Not In (0, -0.07, -0.10, 0.03, 0.05, 0.06, 0.12, 0.13, 0.26) )x;
```

Comment: Have you thought about indexes?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Very simple: remove all the outer joins, you're not using any of those tables in Select or Where (a smart optimizer should do this automatically). And then you might not need `distinct` anymore

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - 11.0.2100.60

Comment: @dnoeth - thanks for replying.   I am using all of those tables - I just took out a lot of the columns to make the statement easier to read.

Comment: @juergen - I am slightly familiar with indexes.  This is a topic I am just getting into.  I will read about indexes further.  Thank you.

Comment: Rule of thumb: You need indexes for the columns in your `where` clause.

Comment: I have to ask - is stackoverflow not a good place for people who are new to coding to ask questions?  I have had at least two people jump down my throat today for not asking a question the right way on other topics.  I think I am being fairly specific.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Who was unfriendly to you in this question??

Comment: Can you show the relations between those tables? I assume you got multiple m:n relations...

Comment: @juergen, not this question

Comment: @dnoeth, I cannot.  The actual query I am working on is for work and I am afraid to show the names of the real tables, fields, etc.  I was trying to make a "fake" version

Comment: Faking table names is not an issue, but by removing the columns of the other tables, you've hidden how you use them, and therefore we can't judge whether other solutions (like `where exists`, like you yourself proposed) would work. Please post a query that is, if not the actual one, at least relevant to what you're doing.

Comment: "Help optimize my query" questions are pointless unless you include the query execution plan

Comment: @mrfishel, I'm late to the party here, but in response to your question about new programmers on Stack Overflow, it can get dicey. Too often, new posters don't include enough detail in their questions, or don't necessarily even know what details are relevant, being as they're new. And yeah, sometimes the comments can seem a bit short. There are some great blog posts about how to approach asking for help on a public forum. This is one that I tend to point folks toward: [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Thank you @Eric Brandt.  I will check out the link.